# How to set a tooltip width dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I want to create a tool-tip that will have flexible size according to the text length. For example, I have the following tool-tip:

[image]

Now, for this text, the width is OK (fixed in the css). But, when I have a very smaller string:

[image]

the tool-tip looks too big. My question is: how do I make the tool-tip flexible according to the text length? Is there a way to do this in the .css maybe? I work with d3.js, so an answer from this point of view would be acceptable too.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

***EDIT:*** I use [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html) in order to accomplish my goal,  my code is something like that (not exactly, but close enough). It would be best to provide an answer based on that example, since my code is too big to post here.

Comment: Can you please show us the HTML structure and CSS? Possibly also make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) recreating your problem. As it currently is this question is too broad to be answered correctly.

Comment: Edited my post, you can find the code you need in the link I've provided.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that with **CSS**, just use `min-width` and `max-width` together instead of `width`

Also you can simply remove `width` from your **CSS** or change it into `width: auto;`

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. Tnx for the answer anyway!

Comment: @Belphegor I've updated the answer, take a look at it

Comment: What an obvious answer, lol! Can't believe I didn't try with removing the width from the css. Tnx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

the css for the tooltops looks like this (according to your link)

```
div.tooltip {   
  position: absolute;           
  text-align: center;           
  width: 60px;                    /* Width and Height are fixed */            
  height: 28px;                 
  padding: 2px;             
  font: 12px sans-serif;        
  background: lightsteelblue;   
  border: 0px;      
  border-radius: 8px;           
  pointer-events: none;         
}
```

Try removing the `width` property of the CSS. Above you can see that this is set to a fixed-width of 60 pixels.

Comment: Yeah, it works like that, tnx for the answer! Anyway, @Mujtaba Fathel has answered few seconds before you, sorry, I should accept his answer. +1 for the answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

This may be best CSS for this. It will adjust its size according to text inside it

```
div.tooltip{
    position: absolute;
                white-space: pre-line;
                pointer-events: none;
                visibility: visible;
                background-color:White;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 5px 0;
                display: block;
                z-index: 1;
                border: 0.5px solid black;
}
```